# What does this floor expression evaluate to?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Consider the expression

$$\left\lfloor\frac{2n-1}{2}\right\rfloor\;:$$

does it make sense that this floor function will evaluate to $n$? Or should it be $n-1$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\frac{2n-1}{2}=n-\frac{1}{2}$, so the floor is $n-1$.

Comment: ...of course assuming that $\;n\;$ ranges over the integers, which seems implicit in the OP's choice of that variable name.